# get post which contain hashtag android facebook android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the json data of the post which contains specific hashtag
for eg if u go to this fb link u will get the post which contaihs the hashtag **https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/tajmahal**

---

I have treid various ways

- graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23tajmahal&type=post&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}

It gives Post search has been **deprecated**","type":"**OAuthException**"

- graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23tajmahal&type=place&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}

It gives all the places which have tajmahal in their name

```html
    "category": "Landmark",
    "category_list": [
        {
            "id": "209889829023118",
            "name": "Landmark"
        }
    ],
    "location": {
        "street": "",
        "city": "Agra",
        "state": "",
        "country": "India",
        "zip": "",
        "latitude": 27.174799,
        "longitude": 78.042111
    },
    "name": "Tajmahal",
    "id": "108571669173264"

},
{

    "category": "Local business",
    "category_list": [
        {
            "id": "165679780146824",
            "name": "Food & Restaurant"
        }
    ],
    "location": {
        "street": "agra",
        "city": "Agra",
        "state": "",
        "country": "India",
        "zip": "",
        "latitude": 27.192731328938,
        "longitude": 78.026342496684
    },
    "name": "Tajmahal Agra",
    "id": "339553856132817"

},
{

    "category": "Automobiles and parts",
    "category_list": [
        {
            "id": "149998721725634",
            "name": "Automotive Repair"
        }
    ],
    "location": {
        "street": "opposite to MARS Shopping, Shafi street, Rayyan Jadheedh",
        "city": "Al Rayyan",
        "state": "",
        "country": "Qatar",
        "zip": "001",
        "latitude": 25.2902476,
        "longitude": 51.4204253
    },
    "name": "Tajmahal automobiles",
    "id": "191178317741786"
```

so anyone can suggest a way to get the post which have certain hashtag from facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook closed access to that endpoint

http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2015/04/03/facebook-might-be-shutting-down-access-to-hashtags-in-its-api/